# Custom Metadata from publication Tridion

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I'm trying to read the value of Custom Metadata from a Publication using ApiClient API.

Below is the code which I'm trying to get the Publication information:

```
ApiClientProvider pcaClientProvider;
ApiClient pcaClient = this.pcaClientProvider.getClient();

Publication publication = pcaClient().getPublication(ContentNamespace.Sites,id,"", null);
```

I couldn't able to get the value of Custom Metadata information from the above Publication.

Comment: Can you confirm which version of DXA and SDL Tridion Sites?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Tridion Stackexchange.

Here you can find the code example to get the publication metadata, I assume you are using DXA 2.2 Java + DXA Model Extension + GraphiQL provider.

```
private static final String PublicationCustomMetadata = "CustomMetadataFieldName";
String PublicationCustomMetadataValue;

Publication publication = apiClientProvider.getClient().getPublication(
                    ContentNamespace.Sites,
                    publicationId,
                    "requiredMeta:" + PublicationCustomMetadata,
                    null);
    String PublicationCustomMetadataValue = publication == null ||
            publication.getCustomMetas() == null ||
            !publication.getCustomMetas()
                    .getEdges()
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(meta -> PublicationCustomMetadata.equals(meta.getNode().getValue()));
```

**Updated:**

In the backend, it will generate something like Graphql query request for customMetas

```
{   
  publication(namespaceId: 1, publicationId:8)
  {
    customMetas(filter: "requiredMeta:CustomMetadataFieldName")  
    {
      edges 
      {
         node 
        {
           key
           value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Velmurugan
Could you please let me know what is the "requiredMeta:" here.

Comment: Updated my answer, The customMetas filter parameter required that requiredMeta: prefix to add metadata fields names with comma separated, customMetas(filter: "requiredMeta:CustomMetadataFieldName,CustomMetadataFieldName2")

Comment: With Graphql query i'm getting null response. Even with  filter or without filter i'm getting null as response. Did you tried this?

Comment: You mean GraphQL IDE you are getting the response null? then there is no metadata associated or published? you can validate to explore GraphQL using in-browser GraphQL IDE:https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2019/03/03/using-an-in-browser-ide-to-explore-sdl-tridion-sites-9-public-content-api-with-graphql/

Comment: Yes, with GraphQL IDE i'm getting null as response. and Yes, the metadata is associated and it's published.

Answer (score 0):

Querying publication custom metadata has not been supported.
Please refer the knowledge-based article published.
https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000014029